# How to get value dynamically added textbox values in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I want to get the values of dynamically added Textbox on submit button in MVC 3.

I am storing the values in hidden field and getting using FromCollection. Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you name your values something like
MyValues[x] where x is a zero based, continuously increasing integer, you can receive the string values as a list of strings named MyValues.

This trick also works for properties if the main model object, if needed.

You should check some articles about how to bind to collections In ASP mvc, they could give you some ideas.

For example http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (written very quickly outside of editor, so may have typos/issues):
Make a view model:

```
public class DynamicTextBoxViewModel
{
    public IList<string> DynamicTextBox { get; set; }

    public int OtherStuffInViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `Get` Action:

```
var model = new YourViewModel
                {
                    DynamicTextBoxList =
                        new List<DynamicTextBox>
                            {
                                new DynamicTextBox
                                    {
                                        TextBoxText = string.Empty,
                                    }
                            },
                    OtherStuffInViewModel = xxx,
                };
return View(model)
```

Then in your `Post` Action:

You would bind everything where you wanted it.

The idea is to move all the data into a ViewModel and pass that around so you gain the benefits of the ViewModel instead of passing around FormCollection - which is sloppier and more error prone.